# How to parse the line that has a specific word in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm letting my python code go through an HTML document and while it does, I need it to find a specific words and then, parse the lines that have the following words

For example

if HTML document looks like this

```
htmlDocument = '''
word 023-213103-2402131025901238923213

bla bla bla

bla bla bla 

word 2512-521-096-07464325

bla bla bla 

bla bla bla 

word 123123-0293231
'''
```

I need my desirableList to look like this after parsing

```
desirableList = [
"word 023-213103-2402131025901238923213",
"word 2512-521-096-07464325",
"word 123123-0293231"
]
```

Comment: I just did this using this Regex

    `^.*\b(word)\b.*$`

But, I still would like to know if there is any other way to do it in a python way.

Comment: That isn’t HTML? I think we need more context for this.

Comment: Yes that is not HTML, but it is very same to the HTML document I am dealing with.

Comment: The solution is heavily dependent on the data format.

Comment: Correct for the most of the cases, but for this one, my example clearly evaluates the concept of the HTML document with no interception.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean by _evaluates the concept of the HTML document with no interception_, can you explain it differently? Also, can you confirm whether or not the word only appears at the start of the line?

Comment: I forgot to mention that regex is practically never the right tool to use when it comes to parsing HTML. Again, it’s difficult to tell because of the lack of detail and context, but regex might be overkill even if this were plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> desirableList  = [s for s in htmlDocument.split("\n") if "word" in s]
>>> desirableList
['word 023-213103-2402131025901238923213', 'word 2512-521-096-07464325', 'word 123123-0293231']
```

Update the conditional, as needed, to get other kinds of results like "line starts with":

```
[s for s in htmlDocument.split("\n") if s.startswith("word")]
```

Comment: Hi, huge thanks for helping. But, can you tell me what is this "s for s" is called? I have never seen anyone use it in that way.

Comment: Isn’t it kind of implied in the OP that the word is always at the start of the line?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I don't think that it changes anything for the solution he provided.

Comment: the first s is the return value (if "word" in s) (for s in array).

Comment: @sanibani I should have made myself clearer. Problems will arise if that word sometimes appears in other areas of the string. For example, `’bla bla word’` will be picked up alongside `’word 023-3464574’`.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant. The thing is there were no other instances like that, so that problem wouldn't arise. Thank you for looking into problem solving in depth.

Comment: @sanibani _there were no other instances like that_ Alright, as long as you're careful that this can **never** happen.